# How to delete rows with less than a certain amount of items or strings with Pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nltk, lda

I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution to this particular case. I want to remove any rows that contains less than 3 strings or items in the lists. My issues will be addressed more clearly further down.

I'm preparing a LDA topic modelling with a large Swedish database in pandas and have limited the test case to 1000 rows. I'm only concerned with a specific column and my approach so far has been as follows:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('/Users/mo/EXP/NAV/afm.db')
sql = """
select * from stillinger limit 1000
"""
dfs = pd.read_sql(sql, con)

plb = """
select PLATSBESKRIVNING from stillinger limit 1000
"""
dfp = pd.read_sql(plb, con);dfp
```

Then I've defined a regular expression where the first argument removes any meta characters while keeping the Swedish and Norwegian language specific letters. The second argument removes words < 3:

```
rep = {
   'PLATSBESKRIVNING': {
     r'[^A-Za-zÅåÄäÖöÆØÅæøå]+': ' ',
     r'\W*\b\w{1,3}\b': ' '}
}

p0 = (pd.DataFrame(dfp['PLATSBESKRIVNING'].str.lower()).replace(rep, regex=True).
  drop_duplicates('PLATSBESKRIVNING').reset_index(drop=True));p0

PLATSBESKRIVNING
0   medrek rekrytering söker uppdrag manpower h...
1   familj barn tjejer kille söker pair ...
2   uppgift blir tillsammans medarbetare leda ...
3   behov operasjonssykepleiere langtidsoppdr...
4   detta perfekta jobbet arbetstiderna vardaga...
5   familj paris barn söker älskar barn v...
6   alla inom cafe restaurang förekommande arbets...
.
.
```

Creating a pandas Series:

```
s0 = p0['PLATSBESKRIVNING']
```

Then:

```
ts = s0.str.lower().str.split();ts

0      [medrek, rekrytering, söker, uppdrag, manpower...
1      [familj, barn, tjejer, kille, söker, pair, vil...
2      [uppgift, blir, tillsammans, medarbetare, leda...
3      [behov, operasjonssykepleiere, langtidsoppdrag...
4      [detta, perfekta, jobbet, arbetstiderna, varda...
5      [familj, paris, barn, söker, älskar, barn, vil...
6      [alla, inom, cafe, restaurang, förekommande, a...
7      [diskare, till, cafe, dubbel, sökes, arbetet, ...
8      [diskare, till, thelins, konditori, sökes, arb...
```

Removing the stop words from the database:

```
r = s0.str.split().apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in mswl]);r

0      [uppdrag, bemanningsföretag, erbjuds, tillägg,...
1      [föräldrarna, citycentre, stort, tomt, mamman,...
2      [utveckla, övergripande, strategiska, frågor, ...
3                   [erfaring, sykepleier, legitimasjon]
4      [arbetstiderna, vardagar, härliga, människor, ...
5      [paris, utav, badrum, båda, yngsta, endast, fö...
6                       [förekommande, emot, utbildning]
7                                                     []
8                                              [thelins]
9      [paris, baby, månader, våning, delar, badrum, ...
```

Creating a new DataFrame and removing the empty brackets:

```
dr = pd.DataFrame(r)
dr0 = dr[dr.astype(str)['PLATSBESKRIVNING'] != '[]'].reset_index(drop=True); dr0

PLATSBESKRIVNING
0   [uppdrag, bemanningsföretag, erbjuds, tillägg,...
1   [föräldrarna, citycentre, stort, tomt, mamman,...
2   [utveckla, övergripande, strategiska, frågor, ...
3   [erfaring, sykepleier, legitimasjon]
4   [arbetstiderna, vardagar, härliga, människor, ...
5   [paris, utav, badrum, båda, yngsta, endast, fö...
6   [förekommande, emot, utbildning]
7   [thelins]
8   [paris, baby, månader, våning, delar, badrum, ...
```

Maintaining the string:

```
dr1 = dr0['PLATSBESKRIVNING'].apply(str);  len(dr1),type(dr1), dr1

0      ['uppdrag', 'bemanningsföretag', 'erbjuds', 't...
1      ['föräldrarna', 'citycentre', 'stort', 'tomt',...
2      ['utveckla', 'övergripande', 'strategiska', 'f...
3             ['erfaring', 'sykepleier', 'legitimasjon']
4      ['arbetstiderna', 'vardagar', 'härliga', 'männ...
5      ['paris', 'utav', 'badrum', 'båda', 'yngsta', ...
6                 ['förekommande', 'emot', 'utbildning']
7                                            ['thelins']
8      ['paris', 'baby', 'månader', 'våning', 'delar'...
```

My issue now is that I want to remove any rows that contains less than 3 strings in the lists, e.g row 3, 6 and 7. Desired result would be like this:

```
0      ['uppdrag', 'bemanningsföretag', 'erbjuds', 't...
1      ['föräldrarna', 'citycentre', 'stort', 'tomt',...
2      ['utveckla', 'övergripande', 'strategiska', 'f...
3      ['arbetstiderna', 'vardagar', 'härliga', 'männ...
4      ['paris', 'utav', 'badrum', 'båda', 'yngsta', ...
5      ['paris', 'baby', 'månader', 'våning', 'delar'...
.
.
```

How can I obtain this? I'm also wondering if this could be done in a neater way? My approach seems so clumsy and cumbersome.

I would also like to remove both indexes and column name for the LDA topic modelling such that I could write it to a text file without the header and the digits of indexes. I have tried:

```
dr1.to_csv('LDA1.txt',header=None,index=False)
```

But this wraps quotation marks "['word1', 'word2', 't.. ]" to the each list of strings in the file.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Best regards
Mo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just measure the number of items in the list and filter the rows with length lower than 3

```
dr0['length'] = dr0['PLATSBESKRIVNING'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
cond = dr0['length'] > 3
dr0 = dr0[cond]
```

Comment: Awesome Mostafa, this solved my question and added an extra dimension to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use apply len and then select data store it in the dataframe variable you like i.e

```
df[df['PLATSBESKRIVNING'].apply(len)>3]
```

Output :

```
                               PLATSBESKRIVNING
0   [uppdrag, bemanningsföretag, erbjuds, nice]
1        [föräldrarna, citycentre, stort, tomt]
2  [utveckla, övergripande, strategiska, fince]
4      [arbetstiderna, vardagar, härliga, männ]
5           [paris, utav, badrum, båda, yngsta]
8         [paris, baby, månader, våning, delar]
```

Comment: This was a really neatly answer to my question and exactly what I initially was looking for. I couldn't mark this one as solved since I marked the first answer, but just want to express my gratitude.